# Using LIKE to search case insensitive over language specific characters (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, unicode, like, string-searching

Using a PostgreSQL database (Collation C, Encoding UTF8) we store data from various languages. This means we also get the special characters for free (e.g. Å, å, ...)

Within an application we now want to perform a case-insensitive search.  Meaning if the user types 'Å' in the search box, the query must also take into account 'å'.
However, using the lower(string) or upper(string) method completely ignores this values when casting.  And as such, no matching records are found...

Is there any way around this?
Using regex it seems one could use \p{L} to compare values, but I need it at the query level so I guess that's a no-go.

On a side-note: we are using Hibernate to create the query.

Comment: It's not the collation but the `lc_ctype` property of the database that makes `upper('Å')` being `'å'`, but unfortunately it cannot be changed dynamically. Maybe you just need  to create your db with an `lc_ctype` that is Unicode-aware.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? With Postgres 10 you might be able to do that using [ICU collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html#COLLATION-CREATE) although your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") probably gets in the way when you try to specify a collation for a query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't see PostgreSQL supporting that part of ICU required to do this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191905/2639

Comment: We're using PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html)

The traditional, non-PG 10 method of this is to the extension [`unaccent`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html).

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
SELECT 'a' = lower(unaccent('Å'));
```

You jam this into a [TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtsconfig.html)

```
WITH unaccent, french_stem;
```

And then magically all of your fts stuff works as English speakers desire.

Comment: Marked as closest to what I wanted to achieve.  Although not entirely feasible given what we wanted to achieve (in that the app is to be distributed worldwide which would mean an awful lot of work).  To work around the issue (using a hibernate criteria) we replace all "special" characters with '_' in the "like".  The disadvantage is that it gives you false positives, but that's still better then having no results found at all...