# Does PostgreSQL support ICU collation's options and settings?

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-10, international-components-unicode

ICU Specifies different [LDML Collation Settings](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Setting_Options). Some of them seem pretty interesting, especially the ones on case and accent,

> - “Ignore accents”: `strength=primary`
> - “Ignore accents” but take case into account: `strength=primary caseLevel=on`
> - “Ignore case”: `strength=secondary`
> - “Ignore punctuation” (completely): `strength=tertiary alternate=shifted`
> - “Ignore punctuation” but distinguish among punctuation marks: `strength=quaternary alternate=shifted` potentially a better method of doing what

You can also see these [documented here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization). Are these ICU options and settings possible with [PostgreSQL 10 ICU collation support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/collation.html)?

```
CREATE COLLATION special (provider = icu, locale = 'en@strength=primary');
SELECT 'Å' LIKE 'A' COLLATE "special"; # returns false
```

I've also tried the [CLDR BCP47](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/bcp47-extension)

> Starting with ICU 54, collation attributes can be specified via locale keywords as well, in the old locale extension syntax ("`el@colCaseFirst=upper`") or in language tag syntax ("el-u-kf-upper"). Keywords and values are case-insensitive. See the [LDML Collation spec, Collation Settings](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Collation_Settings), and the [data file](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/collation.xml) listing the valid collation keywords and their values. (The deprecated attributes kh/colHiraganaQuaternary and vt/variableTop are not supported.)

For that, this looked right

```
CREATE COLLATION special (provider = icu, locale = 'en-ks-level1');
SELECT 'Å' LIKE 'A' COLLATE "special"; # returns false
```

Also tried `en-u-ks-level1` That method seems to be what the docs go for,

```
CREATE COLLATION german_phonebook (provider = icu, locale = 'de-u-co-phonebk');
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer, and some of the links in it: [Specify ICU collations as `ENCODING`, `LC_COLLATE`, and `LC_CTYPE` in Postgres 10](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183762/30859). I asked the person who answered it to address your question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Case insensitive or accent-insensitive collations cannot be used prior to PostgreSQL 12, because internally PostgreSQL considers that strings with a different binary representation are not equal. When the collation-aware comparator says they are equal, it uses the non-collation-aware `strcmp()` function as a [tie-breaker](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAJ3gD9ez9O7scYT46iRXU-1KDfDeSQvJ2Ekzxs7RYGofYfB4cg%40mail.gmail.com), to obtain what Unicode calls a ["deterministic" comparison](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Deterministic_Comparison) without normalization.

Starting with PostgreSQL 12, collations have a **`deterministic`** property, which must be set to `false` to benefit from equality of non-binary equal strings. From [`CREATE COLLATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createcollation.html):

> DETERMINISTIC
>
> Specifies whether the collation should use deterministic comparisons.
>   The default is true. A deterministic comparison considers
>   strings that are not byte-wise equal to be unequal even if they are
>   considered logically equal by the comparison. PostgreSQL breaks ties
>   using a byte-wise comparison. Comparison that is not deterministic can
>   make the collation be, say, case- or accent-insensitive. For that, you
>   need to choose an appropriate LC_COLLATE setting and set the collation
>   to not deterministic here.
>
> Nondeterministic collations are only supported with the ICU provider.

The exact query in the question is not possible with nondeterministic collations because they don't support `LIKE` or any form of pattern matching (as of PostgreSQL 12).
Also the locale should have a `-u-` before the collation subtags, otherwise they're going to be silently ignored by the collator.

What does work as intended:

```
=# CREATE COLLATION special (
     provider = icu, locale = 'en-u-ks-level1', deterministic=false
   );

=# SELECT 'Å' = 'A' COLLATE "special";
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: I wonder if this is possible now with Postgres 12

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: answer rewritten for Postgres 12.

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks. Does not seem to work on Windows though. [This example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c60496165b256244ec6ec6855c59cf57) returns on nothing when run on Windows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: a crash is also [reported](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/58edf560-f277-8993-abe3-22d57dc11c50%40gmx.net) so there seems to be something funky with ICU and Pg 12.0 on Windows. I guess you used the EDB build?

Comment: Yes, I use the EDB build